# Stop recording audio

Tags: java, audio, avaudioplayer, audio-recording

I'm trying to implement simple audio recorder in Java. I found this recorder class online: http://www.jsresources.org/examples/SimpleAudioRecorder.java.html. When I initialize class and call recorder.start() everything works fine. But when I try to stop recording with recorder.stopRecording() it does nothing and recorder keeps recording till i shut down my program. Does enyone have eny suggestion what to do?